# JQuery Resize firing, but not correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

a simple question. 
I am writing a plugin that will add and remove classes based on the current window size but right now i cant even trigger the resize event correctly.

So my code

```
(function(jq) {

jq(window.jQuery, window, document);

 }(function($, window, document) {

 $(function() {
var $window = $(window).width();

 function resize() {
 if($window < 768)
 {
  console.log("Less than 768");
  }
  else {
    console.log("more than 768");
  }
} 
$(window)
.resize(resize)
.trigger('resize');
});}));
```

this code produces always the same value, for example if i load the screen when its less than 768px it will log less than 768, and if i do full screen it will log more than 768px. any help?

Comment: `var $window = $(window).width();` is executed only once, you've to put it into `resize()`.

Comment: so I should put it in an if statement. yea now it works, `if($window.width()<768)`

Comment: That will work too. Not exactly related, but why you're using this complex code instead of simple event attachment?

Comment: i don't see any complex code here, can you explain maybe what you mean by your statement?

Comment: Instead of declaring `resize` function and doing `$(window).resize(resize);`, you've all that code.